# Different vector space over the same field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Basically I'm doing a review of my knowledge on linear algebra and I stopped over this maybe trivial question: to find an additive group $(V; +)$ and a field $F$ for which $V$ can be equipped as a vector space over $F$ in at least two different way (so basically I have to find two different definition of scalar multiplication).

I know a few examples of a field which can be "turned" into a vector space in two or more different ways but I can't find a case which the sum stays the same and the only one that change is the scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, e.g. $V=\mathbb F=\mathbb C$ with the usual addition. Then $c\cdot v=cv$ and $c\cdot v=\bar{c}\,v$ are two different scalar multiplications.

Comment: Very nice, simple and elegant example. +1